# BIRT/Jasper/Pentaho - Ad hoc reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting, pentaho, birt

I'm currently evaluating the main FOSS report generators. One of the features I'm looking for is the ability to manipulate the presentation of data when the report is presented on the browser:

- Resort the results
- Reorder columns
- Regroup the results
- Filter the data

The idea is to let the users play with the results presented to them, without having to create a new report or modify the underlying query. So:

1. Does any of the FOSS versions support such features? (I know some commercial versions do, but at this point it's not what I'm looking for)
2. If (#1 == false), are there any side open-source projects that provide such features?

Would love to get answers regarding either BIRT, JasperReport of Pentaho.

Comment: It seems that in 2014 the only solution is to use legacy ad hoc reporting by Pentaho CE 4.8 (while the current version is 5.0 has this functionality removed in favour of commercial Pentaho Server). SPAGO BI is very promising(they have Ad Hoc reporting on roadmap of 2014) but they have not implemented even basic functionality and the project is very buggy.

Comment: @eran: Please accept a different answer -- the answer I gave is not correct. JasperReports Server Community Edition does not include *ad hoc* queries. See: http://www.jaspersoft.com/editions

Comment: Finally it looks like that a plausible alternative is to roll out something own based on Dynamic Reports or Dynamic Jasper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually. I did some similar research and couldn't find any software doing true ad hoc reports.  OpenReports used to be a good enough thing,  but it seems discontinued.  What Jasper and birt report servers offer (in the oss version) is more of a reporting template repository and some scheduling / automatic reports.  For the ad hoc features you have to get the paid version.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenReports](http://oreports.com/) have some ajax functionalities on web reporting. I am pretty sure that you can use JSF + Jasper Reports to generate a dynamic web report as well.

hope this helps

Comment: OpenReports is not being actively developed at this time

Answer (score 2):

BIRT has a community edition simple report server sample called [BIRT Runtime](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/) that you can deploy on Tomcat.

However as a web application, its functionality is not comparable to JasperReports Server.

[Actuate](http://www.actuate.com/) however, does provide a flagship commercial BIRT Report Server.